# Extract birth/death day from wikipedia with jsoup?

Tags: parsing, jsoup

i want to extract the birth and death day from wikipedia with jsoup. 
For example:

The brith/death day in wikipedia:

```
* 8. September 1157 in Oxford; † 6. April 1199 in Châlus)
```

The birth/death day in html code:

```
* <a href="/wiki/8._September" title="8. September">8. September</a> <a href="/wiki/1157" title="1157">1157</a> in <a href="/wiki/Oxford" title="Oxford">Oxford</a>; † <a href="/wiki/6._April" title="6. April">6. April</a> <a href="/wiki/1199" title="1199">1199</a>
```

Searched output:

```
String birthDate = 8. September 1157;
String deathDate = 6. April 1199;
```

My problem is i dont know how to extract the information, because searching for a tag "a" and the `attr("href")` could return the wrong element, because the elements don't contain infromation if the element is a birth or a death date or another date.

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to get this from?

Comment: all my pages are in a text file

Comment: People can only help if you provide an example of your input, what you've tried so far, and what actual output you want.

Comment: the problem is, the txt file with all the html pages is around 500mb and the file just contains regular html code of wikipedia pages. It was a small problem in my school project where it is not allowed to open the file, because it represents a "very large" file(500 gb++) that cannot be opened every time you want to look how the file is structured.